# How to count both all the records and part of records based on a condition in the same query?

Tags: sql

i try in sql, use this command

```
SELECT year(datecreated) as tahun, jenis_kelamin, COUNT(jenis_kelamin) as jumlah
from santri
GROUP by jenis_kelamin, tahun
```

but it show like this

```
+------+-------------+-----------+
| Tahun|jenis_kelamin| JUmlah    |
+------+-------------+-----------+
| 2009 |    Laki_laki| 5         |
+------+-------------+-----------+
|2010  |  Perempuan  | 7         |
+------+-------------+-----------+
|2010  |  laki-laki  | 6         |
+------+-------------+-----------+
```

i want view in sql like this

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| Tahun| laki-laki | perempuan |Jumlah
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 2009 |    5      | 0         | 5   |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----+
| 2    |    6      | 7         | 13  |
+-----+------------+-----------+-----+
```

i try to modificated my commad but still not alike this

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.  (2) Where does `Tahun = `2` come from?

Comment: How many different jenis_kelamin values to you want to handle?

Comment: i use sql from xampp

Comment: thank u @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT YEAR(datecreated) as tahun,
       SUM(CASE WHEN jenis_kelamin = 'laki-laki' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as lakilaki,
       SUM(CASE WHEN jenis_kelamin = 'Perempuan' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Perempuan,
       COUNT(*) as jumlah
from santri
GROUP by tahun;
```

I am interpreting the `tahun` value in the second row as a typo.